# Updating cached client model with data received from server

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My situation is the following: 
- I have a frontent User model that is most definitely loaded (and I assume cached)
- I have a "/users//profile" API handler that returns that user with some additional keys plus a few other objects related to the profile page

My route handler currently looks like this:

```
App.UserProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params)  {
        return $.getJSON("/api/v1/users/" + params.username + "/profile").then(
            function(profileInfo) {    
                // profileInfo = {"user": userObject, ...}
                // Do something with profileInfo
            }
        );
    }
});
```

In my callback, I'd like to update the cached user model if possible, since I do not believe I should create a new record.

1. Is this the correct way to do this? As in, I'd like to load additional information about the user specific to a particular route.
2. How can I update the frontend model without putting the object in an `uncommited` state?

Comment: are you using ember-data?

Comment: Yes, I am using ember-data.

Comment: I guess what's also interesting is if the model is not cached, it should actually cache the newly created model.

Comment: if you are using ember-data, then why are you doing your own xhr requests and not letting the RESTAdapter work for you?

Comment: I'm trying to get all the data I need within a single request.